# Java EE Tag Library with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, taglib

I'm import the Java EE standard tag library into jsp page but it does not function properly(Not working). What is the reason ? Is it relate to Spring MVC or servlet 3.0 ?

I'm include the tag library using

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld" prefix="c"%>
```

This tld is located at /WEB-INF/tld.

AFAIK, servlet 3.0 allows us to include tag library using application URI such as //127.0..0.1/apps/c.tld

If this is allow in servlet 3.0, kindly provide an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Kindly provide any guidance. Please let me know if need further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding c.tld file and refer from jsp page